# [React Native]Navigation not working (Cannot change screen) when using external component

Tags: react-native

The link to my code is: https://snack.expo.io/@demonicaoi/cash-trackerro

My bottom navigation bar is in bottom_tab.js , and the main screen is 'Home' which code is at HomeScreen.js .  The navigation parts in the bottom_tab.js do not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `navigation` to your custom bottom tab component:

```
<BottomTab navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```